# How to format Python lists as an HTML list using Jinja2?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, jinja2

Given the elements of the following lists, which express the columns of a table:

```
table1 = [('January', '$5'),('February', '$9000'), ('October', '$90'), ('NaN', '$300')]
table2 = [('July', '$890'),('December', 'NaN')]
```

And this **html base template**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Table element 1</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>month</td>
    <td>amount</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>This is the status X</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="valn" name="valn" value="val_n"> Validate

</body>
</html>
```

What is the best way to fill with the template's table with the list's values? and extend the table structure for more pairs of lists (columns). For example, for the above lists of tubles, this should be the filled version of the html template:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Table element 1</h1>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NaN</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <h2>This is the status A</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="checkbox" id="val1" name="val1" value="val_1"> Validate
    </form>
    
    <h1>Table element 2</h1>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>December</td>
        <td>NaN</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <h2>This is the status B</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" id="val2" name="val2" value="val_2"> Validate
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Although I could handle this with some string manipulation I think that theres a cleaner way of doing this with jinja. However, I do not know how to control different elements from the template such as the tables and checkboxes. Any idea of how to get the above output, for two and n lists of tuples?

Comment: You might want to use a Jinja `{% for %}` tag in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LeMinaw, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested in comments (basically the same as @nenadp's answer since it was corrected):

```
from jinja2 import Template


table1 = [('January', '$5'), ('February', '$9000'), ('October', '$90'), ('NaN', '$300')]
table2 = [('July', '$890'), ('December', 'NaN')]

table = table1 + table2 # Concatenate the two lists

template = Template("""
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for row in table %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
""")

print(template.render(table=table))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. To build the template from the string seem to be a good feature of jinja. For example, if I want to add more tables and check boxes what should be the correct way of doing it? Should I just append it as a string or is there more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Also, I guess the output is wrong. You are concatenating horizontally, instead of doing it vertically

Comment: The standard way is to have your template containing html code + Jinja tags in a separate file, and to load and render it in your Python module. Really, you should dig in the docs, it's well explained AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, missed a `tr` tag. Should be good now.

Answer (score -1):

Change your template file:

```
{% for row in table1 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You can format it using this piece of code:

```
from jinja2 import Template

table1 = [('January', '$5'),('February', '$9000'), ('October', '$90'), ('NaN', '$300')]

t = open('template_file.html', 'r').read()  
template = Template(t)
formatted_template = template.render(table1=table1)
print(formatted_template)
```

You can learn more from [Jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

Comment: Could you provide a more comprensive example? As I said I am not familiar with jinja, and I already check the docs, and some examples.

Comment: Edited comment. There's a piece of code for your template and data.